# Cannot see profile when creating new user

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I'm using the Developer edition of Salesforce, following this tutorial: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/index.htm

I've got to the stage where I have to create users in certain profiles.

I have created a profile called Recruiter, and its User License is shown as Salesforce.

Now, I go to create a new user, I select Salesforce Platform for the User License, but then the only profile available in the drop down is Standard Platform User.  In fact, no matter which User License I select (Force.com, Chatter Free or Salesforce Platform), I still can't see the Recruiter profile in the Profile dropdown.

Further, I have 24 profiles created in total - some were created automatically for me when I signed up, and others are from various experiments - but the vast majority of these never appear for selection on the New User page.  The only ones I ever see are (depending on which User License I select) are:

- Force.com - Free User
- Chatter Free User
- Chatter - Moderator
- Standard Platform User

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You created the Recruiting profile with a Salesforce user license, so it is only going to appear as an option for users with the Salesforce user license; however, if you do not have any Salesforce user licences available, that option will not appear in the user license picklist when creating a new user. So, you have two options:

- Inactivate an existing user with a Salesforce user license, which will free up the license, and then try to create your new user. Your org might only have one Salesforce license, which you are using yourself as an admin, so this probably is not the best option. You can see how many licenses you have by going to Setup | Company Profile | Company Info.
- Delete the existing Recruiter profile, re-create a new one with a different user license type, and then associate that with your new user.